# ER_UNKNOWN_STMT_HANDLER when executing a batch insert

Tags: node.js, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Trying to do a batch insert, but I keep hitting a `ER_UNKNOWN_STMT_HANDLER` error.

I managed to rewrite it useing `query`, but I would like to figure out how to do it using `batch`

Here is the code I have:

```
result = await conn.batch("INSERT INTO `a11yUIDB`.`TEST_questions` (`name`,`address`,`text`,`match`,`type`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [[ 'Four', 'add one', 'te `', 'Yes', 'No' ],[ 'Five', 'add one', 'te `', 'No', 'No' ]]);
```

Full Error:

```
(conn=1136, no: 1243, SQLState: HY000) Unknown prepared statement handler (0) given to mysqld_stmt_execute
sql: INSERT INTO `a11yUIDB`.`TEST_questions` (`name`,`address`,`text`,`match`,`type`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) -
parameters:[['Four','add one','te `','Yes','No'],['Five','add one','te `','No','No']]
```

Environment: Node

MariaDB Version: 10.3.13

Comment: did you use maxscale or just connecting directly to database server ?

Comment: Connected directly